# How to find inactive object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find and active inactive object: Main Menu.
I try this code, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            GameObject.Find("Main Menu").SetActive(true);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the parent gameobject to inactive first. Try this:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        GameObject.Find("Main Menu").SetActive(true);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

The easiest way to do this is to create a public reference at the top of your class, like so:

`public GameObject MainMenu;`

Then, in the editor, drag the MainMenu object over to the newly created reference.
After that, in your logic, you may simply do this:

```
    public GameObject MainMenu;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        MainMenu.SetActive(true);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Doing it this way helps to prevent null references, as it is type safe.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object dx.Update () (at Assets/dx.cs:17)

Comment: Make 100% sure that the "Main Menu" object is named "Main Menu". It is case sensitive and has to match EXACTLY with what you type in GameObject.Find().

Comment: Try doing what I posted in my edit.

Comment: I have that: https://prnt.sc/irnxy7. I am at "Logowanie" and I want to active "Glowne menu"

Comment: Create a public reference, drag and drop it into the slot in the editor, and access it via your variable instead of making Unity search for it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am beginner and I don't understand :(

Comment: The last codeblock in my post should be all you need.

Comment: I still don't know what I should to do :(

Comment: Then unfortunately you're going to need to start from the beginning. If you don't know what a public variable is, or how Unity handles them, you're going to have a really hard time trying to complete a game. Just go back and read the beginners tutorials, watch beginners videos, etc, until it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Either a reference to the object before setting it off or create your own method since you have them all under the same parent object you can use GetComponentsInChildren

```
public static GameObject FindObject(this GameObject parent, string name)
 {
     Transform[] trs= parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
     foreach(Transform t in trs){
         if(t.name == name){
              return t.gameObject;
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

this is an extension method that should be stored in a static class. You use it like this:

```
GameObject obj = parentObject.FindObject("Main Menu");
```